# how to work range validators for strings?

Tags: asp.net, rangevalidator

however my question is simple but I don't know it's answer.  I use range validators in my project. I know how they work for integer or float or dates but I don't know how they works for strings. for example if the min value is "xx" and the max value is "zzyyyz" ,what the users can  enter? can you get me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of the [`RangeValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f70d09xt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it appears you can specify a string type:

```
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server"
                    MaximumValue="zz"
                    MinimumValue="xx" 
                    Type="String" 
                    ... />
```

Although you may be better off using a [`RegularExpressionValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). In this example, you'd have:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server"
                                ValidationExpression="^[x-z]{2}$"
                                ... />
```

Comment: but my purpose of this question is that what strings can be entered. xx and  zz just are an example.

Comment: @Angel See the first part of my answer. If you tried it and it's producing the result you expected, please include that as part of your question.

Comment: my question is when we determine min string  and max string , how it works? in fact what strings  are allowable for users?

Comment: @Angel I imagine it does something like `string.Compare(input, minimumValue) >= 0 && string.Compare(input, maximumValue) <= 0`

Comment: what does it compare? just number of charcters?

Comment: @Angel [`string.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare.aspx) compares each character. I'm not entirely sure that `RangeValidator` uses that technique, but I believe it does. If you have doubts, try it out (I don't have the ability to test it myself at the moment).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32649/discussion-between-angel-and-p-s-w-g)